# Что такое "хны"?

Tags: этимология

Откуда взялось выражение *"хоть бы хны",* и что означает это *"хны"?*

Answer (score 3):

***ХНЫ*** — звукоподражательное слово, которым передаются звуки всхлипывания. (Отсюда ***хныкать***.)

***ХОТЬ БЫ ХНЫ***  =  совершенно безразлично.  Первоначально: «хоть бы заплакал»  (от наказания).

(Версия отсюда: *"Русский язык в школе", выпуски 4 — 6, 2003*.)

Comment: Спасибо, Слава!

Answer (score 2):

"Хны" в данном случае  ― любой неопределенный звук (необязательно хныканье, плач), а "хоть бы хны" ― это **безразличное молчание**, полное отсутствие какой-либо эмоциональной реакции на происходящее.

[Что такое ХНЫ? | Ответы Mail.Ru](https://otvet.mail.ru/question/36342194) Словом "хны" **обозначался и любой неясный звук, произносимый человеком в ответ на обращение.** Т. е. исходный смысл выражения "хоть бы хны" - хоть бы голос подал, среагировал как-то (Шанский и др. , **"Опыт этимологического словаря русской фразеологии", М. 1987).**

"Была такая присказка (говорят, и сейчас есть): хоть бы хны рубаха долга, и коротка ― хоть бы хны".

**Но история фразеологизма не очень ясна**, до 1900 года в Нацкорпусе его нет. Там самое раннее употребление в следующем тексте: 
Все кругом изрешечено, а эта кукла цела ― хоть бы хны!.. [А. П. Хейдок. Три осечки (1924-1934)]

**Из словаря**

<ХНЫ>, межд. ◊ Хоть бы хны. Разг.-сниж. 1. **кто**. Кто-л. совершенно равнодушен, никак не реагирует. Прошу отремонтировать телевизор, а он хоть бы хны! -2. **кому**. Совершенно безразлично кому-л., совершенно не трогает, не волнует кого-л. Учитель сердится, а им хоть бы хны!

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! А Вам не кажется, что "необязательно" в Вашем ответе лучше раздельно написать?

Comment: А  почему? Здесь авторское решение, возможны обе формы. Можно сказать "совершенно необязательно" ― тогда это точно утвердительная форма. При отрицании слово выделяется логическим ударением, подчеркивается,  а в моем предложении этого нет. Вообще говоря, я стараюсь использовать отрицание только при необходимости, так как выбор отрицательной конструкции при наличии утвердительного варианта желательно как-то объяснить.

Comment: Просто я воспринял так, что в начале опущено слово "это", и тогда, если я правильно понимаю, "не обязательно" — сказуемое. Правильно? А разве можно написать "это необязательно хныканье"? Если я прав и при раздельном написании это сказуемое, чем это будет при слитном написании? Заранее спасибо за Ваши комментарии!

Comment: **Sibylla**: _"**Была такая присказка**: хоть бы хны рубаха долга, и коротка ― хоть бы хны"_. === Была. И есть. У Коловой Ольги Викторовны в её частушке "Пятачок". Только какое отношение имеет эта частушка **к происхождению** "хоть бы хны"? === _Милка ходит так и сяк, Думат — любит ее всяк. Лучше черный деготь пить, Чем тебя, милка, любить.  **Хоть бы хны** — рубаха долга. И не долга — **хоть бы хны**. **Хоть бы хны** — девчата любят. И не любят — **хоть бы хны**._

Comment: Присказка-частушка определяет современное значение и область употребления фразеологизма. Что касается происхождения, то информацию о нем лучше искать в этимологических словарях или других подобных источниках.

Comment: Артем, здесь "необязательно" - это обстоятельственное наречие,  и оно может относиться к различным словам (связь примыкание). Например: Это любой звук, необязательно плач (= а не только плач).  Другой пример: Негатив может нести любой  предмет, необязательно одежда. Здесь имеют место  грамматически однородные отношения (предмет, одежда),  а семантику этих отношений уточняет наречие (или частица с союзом).